# How to transform array of objects into nested array groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Example data:

```
var people = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }
];
```

I'm trying to group together an array of objects based on a property of the objects. I attempted using _.groupBy, but that returns an object and not an array. Is there a similar function that can transform into the below result?

Desired result

```
var newPeople = [
  [
    { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
    { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' },
    { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' },
    { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` and then `values` and get array of arrays.

```js
var people = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }
];

var result = _.values(_.groupBy(people, 'gender'))
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If we have multiple array of keys in groupBy then how will we achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of groupBy you could use lodash's [**partition**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partition):

```
let result = _.partition(people, {gender: 'male'})
```

or to have them in seperate variables, add a dash of destructuring:

```
let [males, females] = _.partition(people, {gender: 'male'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` to get unique `"gender"` properties, `.Array.from()` and `.filter()` to create an array of arrays of results of filtered matches

```js
var people = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }
];


let res = Array.from(new Set(people.map(({gender}) => gender))
          , g => people.filter(({gender}) => gender === g));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for the groups and iterate the array while using the group for pushing.

```js
var people = [{ name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' }, { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' }, { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' }, { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' }, { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    newPeople = [];
    
people.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!groups[o.gender]) {
        groups[o.gender] = [];
        newPeople.push(groups[o.gender]);
    }
    groups[o.gender].push(o);
});

console.log(newPeople);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a good old `for` loop ?

```js
var groups = {};
var newPeople = [];
var people = [
  { name: 'John', age: 30, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Kelly', age: 31, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Stephanie', age: 30, gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Dan',  age: 28, gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Crystal', age: 29, gender: 'female' }
];
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  let gender = people[i]["gender"];
  if (!groups[gender]) groups[gender] = [];
  groups[gender].push(people[i]);
}
for (let gender in groups) {
  newPeople.push(groups[gender]);
}
console.log(newPeople);
```

Comment: nice! I agree, it could be, and maybe should be, a for loop. However, my project already included lodash and I figured, why not leverage?